# Android Studio flavor and customizing inspection in it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors

As adviced by Google, I created a flavor in Android Studio where I increased min-sdk version to 23. This is promised to speedup build/test cycle.
Release builds of the app are using lower minSdkVersion.

Anyway, no matter what's reason, the flavors are there and allow to change minSdkVersion and other stuff.

Now the problem. As I develope with activating such build flavor, I suddenly get warnings from code inspector like this:

[image]

that is, inspector now sees that Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is some constant and pollutes my clean code with warnings.

Can I somehow disable the inspection warning? Ideally only for those one flavor.

Comment: Remove the if you don't need it

Comment: @Vaudey Baptiste: read 1st paragraph, I need it for other flavor (release build)